# hidden div not shown on hover from all sides Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, performance, magento, hover

Hi i need to display the the hidden div on hover , for that i have create a below jquery function

```
<script>
var con =jQuery.noConflict();   
con(document).ready(function(){
con(".loop").hover(function() {
    con(this).find('span.soc').show();
},function() {
con( this ).find( "span.soc" ).hide();
});

con("span.soc").hover(function() {
    con(this).hide();
});




});
</script>
```

and below is the html code

```
     <td class="loop"><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image">
    <?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail(); ?>"
 style="width:75px;height:53px;" 
    alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?>


    <span class="soc" > <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image">
    <?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail(); ?>" style="width:250px;height:160px;" 
    alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?>

     </span>
    </td>
```

> it works fine but there is one strange issue in this
>
> when i hover it from right, top and bottom it shws the hidden div
>
> but when i hover from the left side it doenot work.

**Please suggest e whee i am doing mistake**

Answer (score 0):

ok i got the issue this was happen due to

```
con("span.soc").hover(function() {
    con(this).hide();
});
```

which hide the div on hover , but now i got another issue anow when i hovr over the soc div it doesnot get hide , i need to hide that on hover also

please suggest some ideas